# Need help in reading variable

Tags: text-processing

I'm currently getting acquainted with Ubuntu. I have a personal project that deals with multiple bash files.

I have a file `config.txt` with the following strings:

```
hostip="192.168.1.2"
pname="My Office"
pid="01-001"
```

My question is, If I have a bash file that needs `hostip` variable from `config.txt` file, how do I extract the `192.168.1.2` string (the double quotes should be stripped from the output)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -n "s/hostip=\([^ ]*.*\)/\1/p" config.txt
```

But if your config.txt contains spaces in the declaration, like `hostip = 192.168.1.2`, use:

```bash
sed -n "s/hostip *= *\([^ ]*.*\)/\1/p" config.txt
```

Finally, to make life easier, create a function or a wrapper script:

```bash
get_value() { 
    sed -n "s/$1 *= *\([^ ]*.*\)/\1/p" $2
}

get_value hostip config.txt
# prints 192.168.1.2
get_value pname config.txt
# prints My Office

hostip=$(get_value hostip config.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to accomplish that, for example:

```bsh
$ awk -F'"' '/hostip/ {print $2}' host.txt
192.168.1.2
```

- The `-F` option determines the field separator
- `/hostip/` determines the search string
- and `{print $2}` determines the field to be printed

And with that, you can get this string from a file and put it in a variable inside your bash script, for example:

```bsh
hostip=$(awk -F'"' '/hostip/ {print $2}' host.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl6)**

```
~$ raku -ne 'put $/ if m/ <?after  hostip\= > \" <([\d**1..3 \.]**3 \d**1..3)> \" /;' config1.txt
192.168.1.2
```

The `-ne` command line flags tell Raku to examine input line-by-line. The code above uses a positive zero-width lookbehind assertion, written `<?after … >`.   The regex looks for a match of four sets of digits, each 1-to-3 digits in length, each separated by a period. The `<( … )>` idiom tells Raku to drop every outside match and load the inner match into the `$/` match variable, which is returned.

HTH.

https://raku.org